# Refresh Vs. Reload (Cannot call method 'authorize' of undefined) GAPI

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have a simple gapi (Google Drive) app that I want to connect to. There something strange that happening. I have the sample from the demo. https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js

```
//Nothing happens
<script src="static/javascript/libs/client.js?onload=Drive._handleClientLoad"></script>

//Works on reload but not refresh
// (reload) "successfully authorization"
// (refresh) "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'authorize' of undefined"
<script src="static/javascript/libs/client.js" onload="Drive._handleClientLoad"></script>
```

**Javascript**:

---

```
var Drive = {

  _CLIENT_ID: '61183508825.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  _SCOPES: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
  _rootid: null,
  authorised: false,

  _auth: function() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      'client_id': Drive._CLIENT_ID, 'scope': Drive._SCOPES, 'immediate': true
    },Drive._handleAuthResult);
  },

  _handleClientLoad: function() {
    window.setTimeout(Drive._auth, 1);
  },

  _handleAuthResult: function(authResult)  {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    // Access token has been successfully retrieved, requests can be sent to the API.
      Drive._validAuth();
    } else {
      // No access token could be retrieved, show the button to start the authorization flow.
      Drive._invalidAuth();
    }
  },

  _invalidAuth: function(){
    Drive.authorised = false;
    console.log("invalid authorization");
  },

  _validAuth: function(){
    Drive.authorised = true;
    console.log("successfully authorization");
  },

 }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The answer to your question is probably that for refresh, the js is cached so is not reparsed and thus the js statement therein that creates the gapi object isn't being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but I can't call `Drive._handleClientLoad` from the `..client.js?onload=` function, so creating a public one like bellow and it works.

```
function handleClientLoad() {
  window.setTimeout(Drive._checkAuth, 1);
}

// ..client.js?onload=handleClientLoad
```

Answer (score 1):

The html should be as per your first snippet. You need to figure out why "nothing happens". It might be some limitation in the Google lib that prevents it from calling into a module. Try replacing `Drive._handleClientLoad` with a global function that in turn calls your module. Perhaps sprinkle a few console.log's or debugger's in to see what is being executed and what isn't.

Comment: If I create a new `<script>function test(){alert(1)}</script>` in the same file and call it as `?onload=test` it doesn't work ether.

Comment: I just noticed the URL. Have you downloaded a local copy of the js library?

Comment: Yes, and i tried the `api.google.com/.... ` one no difference. Is it something to do with cross domains?

Comment: the google js must be loaded from Google as per the quickstart instructions. It's not valid to have your own copy.

Comment: As mentions above I tried it and it's still not working.

Comment: You need to roll your code back to the quickstart and then figure out why that isn't working. The more yoy deviate from that, the harder it will be to resolve as you have bugs on bugs.